# iOS - strange openURL issue opening wrong app

Tags: ios, uri, instagram-api, deep-linking, url-scheme

I have an app in prod, and there's a feature that opens the instagram app for the user to post a photo. It works perfectly fine, unless the user has this [horoscope app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-dailyhoroscope/id363920434?mt=8) installed, then when the user clicks the button, it opens the horoscope app instead of instagram.

Does this mean the horoscope app has the same URL scheme as instagram? Are there any safeguards built-in to prevent other apps using your URL scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not enforce unique naming for app schemes. If you use the same scheme as another app, iOS has no way of knowing which App to launch. So yes both apps are using same URL scheme. 
You can use Document Interaction API, if you just want to share via Instagram. 
You can find more information [HERE](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)

Answer (score 1):

For me this was happening because I added the "googlegmail" key to the "URL Schemes" key in the in Info.plist instead of the "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" key.

The LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key was the correct one to add "googlegmail" to in order to be able to open gmail from my app.

Having the "googlegmail" key in the "URL Schemes" section essentially told iOS that my application could open urls with the googlegmail:// URL prefix which was incorrect, as my app isn't gmail.